# Users dashboard and reports do not display correctly

Tags: 2013, permissions, settings

When certain users go to their dashboard, the dashboard and subsequently the reports don't display correctly. When I use their computer, as them, and I log onto my dashboard, it does display correctly.

I think it has to do with permissions because adding the users to the IT group the dashboard and reports display correctly.

Could the permissions determine how a report is displayed? It's like the users settings (permissions) determine if the report can read html or not.

This is the what a User report looks like[image: USERS_REPORT] this is what the same report looks like on same computer, same user on that computer, but with admin credentials[image: ADMIN_Report]

Comment: Edit the post anduse the image icon to post a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The user doesn't have access to one or more CSS files, most likely corev15.css is one of them. To confirm, you could use Fiddler or the F12 developer tools in the browser to record the network traffic to see which specific files to showing an access denied message.

But let me take a guess: Corev15.css is available to all users by default. Perhaps someone tried to modify it and made a copy of that file and the user doesn't have permission to the copy? Perhaps it's as simple as the fact that  a copy of corev15.css has been referenced, but the corev15.css file is not checked in, or doesn't have a major version published/approved? Again, this is a guess, the better answer is to use fiddler or f12 tools to track it down. So:

In IE:

1. hit f12, which should open the developer tools in a panel or a separate window.
2. Switch to the "network" tab.
3. click the green start button.
4. refresh the browser window
5. watch in the developer window/panel as every single network call is displayed. Look for calls to CSS files that don't have a result of 200.

If you identify a CSS file that is not loading successfully, you'll need to find out why. Again, common issues are the file not being checked in, not having a major version published or approved, or permission issues.

edit: here's the menu to get to all site content:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23097/discussion-on-answer-by-mike2500-users-dashboard-and-reports-do-not-display-corr).